# How accept() differs from bind() and connect()?

Tags: sockets, tcp

Consider the following code for accepting connections:

```
struct sockaddr_in peer_addr;
socklen_t peer_addr_size = sizeof (struct sockaddr);
int peer_fd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr, &peer_addr_size);
```

In `accept(2)` it is said:

> The `addrlen` argument is a value-result argument: the caller must initialize it to  contain  the
>   size  (in bytes) of the structure pointed to by `addr`; on return it will contain the actual size
>   of the peer address.

On the other hand, `bind` and `connect` do not set the size of structure, pointed to by `addr`:

```
struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &my_addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr));
```

```
struct sockaddr_in peer_addr;
peer_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
peer_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
peer_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ADDR);
connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr));
```

**EDIT**

It is not clear in which cases "actual size of the address" may be useful.
If the "actual size of the address", obtained from peer, is useful somehow, then "actual size of the address" must also be useful when obtained from local host. Then there must be a way to get "actual size of the address" for `struct sockaddr` which is used in `connect` and `bind`, because neither `bind` nor `connect` does that. So, how do we obtain them in cases when `accept` is not used?
And why `bind` and `connect` do not set "actual size of the address".

OS: Linux

Answer (score 1):

The address parameter is an output in `accept()`, but an input in `bind()` and `connect()`. So both it and its associated length value-result parameter need to be writable in `accept()` and not in `bind()` and `connect()`.

Comment: It is also input parameter in `accept` - see "the caller must initialize it". The question is why `addr` is not "output parameter" in `bind` and `connect`? (or equivalently, why `addr` is "output parameter" in `accept`). In which circumstances exactly we may need "actual size of the address"?

Comment: No. Read what I wrote. The address parameter is only an output parameter in `accept()`. The address-*length* parameter is also an input, or, to use the words that both I and the document you quoted used, a value-result parameter. They aren't output parameters in `bind()` and `connect()` because these functions read them, not write them, because of their semantics. You are telling *them* what to bind or connect to: `accept()` tells *you* the remote address of the connecting client.

Comment: If the "actual size of the address", obtained from peer, is useful somehow, then
 "actual size of the address" must also be useful when obtained from local host.
 Then there must be a way to get "actual size of the address" for `struct sockaddr` which is used in `connect` and `bind`...

Comment: When obtained from the local host how? Neither `bind()` nor `connect()` does that. *You* obtain it, somehow, and you supply it and its length *to* these functions. Not the other way around. I've already stated all this twice.

Comment: I supply `sizeof (struct sockaddr)` to `bind` and `connect`, not "actual size of the address". In first comment I meant "address-length" instead of `addr`. Also, see EDIT in OP.

Comment: I agree. You supply `addrlen` by value to `bind()` and `connect()`, and by value-reference to `accept()`, for the reasons I have now stated three times. It really should have sunk in already. Have a look at some sample TCP client and server code.

Comment: It is not clear why we may need "actual size of the address" in one case, but not in other two cases.

Comment: **Because the other two cases don't write the address: they only read it.** How many times does this need to be stated? Four times now. *You* know the address, and its actual length, you are binding or connecting to. You don't need to be told it again. It doesn't change.

Comment: I don't know the actual length of address I'm binding or connecting to, I only know `sizeof (struct sockaddr)` (actual size is 16 bits on 64-bit machines, and 8 bits on 32-bit machines, whereas `sizeof (struct sockaddr)` is 16 bits on all machines). **The main point of the question:** Do you know any specific example when we actually *use* "actual address size" returned by `accept`? (I mean when it can be different from `sizeof (struct sockaddr)`)

Comment: You do know it, and you have supplied it, as `sizeof struct sockaddr`. This is neither 8 nor 16 bits; it is always the same; and it doesn't vary between 32- and 64-bit machines. It only varies as between IPv4 and IPv6. In any case, for the fifth time, neither `bind()` nor `connect()` modifies it, or needs to. The 'main point of the question', now that you have finally stated it, is answered by any piece of code that stores or displays or converts the address of the connected client: it can't do so correctly without knowing its length, which is an output of `accept()`.